# Simulation on LTSpice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, spice

LTSpice does not have a gap sensor as a component. Is there anyway I can either download a gap sensor or is there a way to create my own one.[image: Scematic]

Comment: It looks like you're talking about a tool that you do not know how to use. I recommend to open the manual (`F1`) and read it at least once (optionally [ltwiki](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Main_Page) for additional info). It may prove spartan, terse, but it has information that is readily available without having to wait for hours for answers to such a generic question as this.

Comment: Gap sensor as in capacitive gap sensor?

Comment: @laptop2d As in an Optical sensor

Comment: @JaredJoss can you provide a schematic of what you intend to model. There are usually ways to model sensors as current or voltage sources in spice to get design parameters

Comment: @laptop2d I have added the scematic

Comment: Do you mean an infrared detector/emitter pair that tells you when there is an object blocking the light between the emitter and the detector?

Comment: @JRE Yes that is correct, sorry for the bad explanantion

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother.  Just aim to buy one/pair and assume it works as spec'd.  Then model it's output as a pulse train using a voltage source. Something like this?

[image: sensor]

It has a [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/14ae/0900766b814ae509.pdf) that shows it operating with an open collector output. See the following test circuit, and adapt for your device. You don't need to model it in detail as the manufacturer will stand by it's operation.  I'm also assuming that you're not using it in some weird way like relying on it as a current source etc.  If you only need it as a logic level switch, the pulse train/voltage source should work fine.  This is a recommended serving suggestion:-

[image: model]